# Controller return type in Asp.Net Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public Visitor Get(string id)
    {
        var result = _visitorRepository.GetFromDB(id);

        if (result == _visitorRepository.GetFromDB(id))
            return StatusCode(200);
        if (result != null)
            return result;
        else
            return StatusCode(408);
    }
```

It gives me an error because StatusCode has ActionResult return type

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult Get(string id)
    {
        var result = _visitorRepository.GetFromDB(id);

        if (result == _visitorRepository.GetFromDB(id))
            return StatusCode(200);
        if (result != null)
            return result;
        else
            return StatusCode(408);
    }
```

It gives me an error because result has Visitor return type

I need only one method but I cannot convert the returning type from ActionResult to visitor and vice versa.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What's the error, for example?

Comment: Use `return Ok()` and `return Ok(result)`.

Comment: See the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Cannot implicitily convert type 'Microsoft .AspNetCore.Mvc.StatusCodeResult' to class Visitor

Comment: You need `IActionResult` (or maybe `ActionResult` works too) as the return type. The docs list the possible methods, take a look at them.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Check my answer and comments below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can correct both of your functions as per below explanation.

In case your first function:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
    public Visitor Get(string id)
    {
        var result = _visitorRepository.GetFromDB(id);

        if (result != _visitorRepository.GetFromDB(id))
            return StatusCode(200); // Somehow make this to return "Visitor" type
        if (result != null)
            return result;  // Somehow make this to return "Visitor" type
        else
            return StatusCode(408); // Somehow make this to return "Visitor" type
    }
```

If you want to go with the second function then make the following changes:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult Get(string id)
    {
        var result = _visitorRepository.GetFromDB(id);

        if (result != _visitorRepository.GetFromDB(id))
            return Ok();
        if (result != null)
            return Ok(result); // Return type of ActionResult
        else
            return BadRequest();
    }
```

Just for your reference `ActionResult` for `StatusCode(200)` return type could be like

```
return Ok();
```

Comment: You can use like: [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
        {
            var result = _visitorRepository.GetFromDB(id);
            if (result != null) return Ok(result); else return NotFound();
        }

Comment: You need to return Ok(result) instead of just result. And if that also does not help then change the return type to IHttpActionResult

Answer (score 0):

```
return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);  // OK = 200
```

https://forums.asp.net/t/2084457.aspx?How+do+I+return+HttpStatus+codes+in+ASP+NET+Core+1+0+API+

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to use this in OP's example? It's not really clear.

Comment: I too agree with you @John if one is answering its answer should be clear enough in term of solution and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(string id)
{
  if (id == null)
  {
    return BadRequest();
    var result = _visitorRepository.GetFromDB(id);
  }
  if (result != null)
    return Ok(result);

  else
    return NotFound();
}
```

Comment: If I am not wrong you should appreciate the efforts of SO member and accept or upvote their answer as your answer seems to be motivated with RAGHVENDER answer.